# array out of bounds adding a byte array to another

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

Working on a bit of crypto and ran into an array out of bounds exception. I traced through it a few times on paper and all seems okay to me so i cant really determine the origin of the error. If anyone could help that would be awesome!

```
   static byte[] encrypt(byte[] ptBytes, javax.crypto.SecretKey key, byte[] IV){

    byte [] ct; 
    byte [] pt;
    byte [] ptBlock, ctBlock;
    int bytes;              //the number of bytes left over in the last block // this comes into play w/ the last 2 blocks witht the swap and stuff

    //get the extra bytes in case last block of plain text isn't whole
    bytes = ptBytes.length%16;

    //pad the plain text array to proper length
    pt = Arrays.copyOf(ptBytes, (((ptBytes.length )/16) + 1) * 16 );
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pt));

    //ctBlock = one block of cipher text
    ctBlock = new byte [16];

    //make ct the length of the padded pt 
    ct = new byte [pt.length];

    //do the encryption
    //i is for the current block of plain / cipher text we are on
    for( int i = 1; i <= ((ptBytes.length )/16)+1; i++){
        if( i == 1 ){

            //make ptBlock the first block of the entire plain text
            ptBlock = Arrays.copyOfRange(pt, 0, (i*16));

            //since i = 1 do the XOR to get new plain text with IV
            for (int j = 0; j < ptBlock.length - 1; j++){
                ptBlock[j] = (byte)(ptBlock[j] ^ IV[j]);
            }

            //now time to do the encryption between the current block of plain text and the key
            try {
                ctBlock = AES.encrypt(ptBlock, key);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //now put the cipher text block we just got into the final cipher text array
            for( int k = 0; k < ctBlock.length; k++){
                ct[k] = ctBlock[k];
            }


        }
        else{
            //make ptBlock the current number block of entire plain text
            ptBlock = Arrays.copyOfRange(pt, (i-1)*16, (i*16));

            //now XOR the plain text block with the prior cipher text block
            for(int j = 0; j < ptBlock.length - 1; j++){
                ptBlock[i] = (byte) (ptBlock[j] ^ ctBlock[j]);
            }

            //now time to do the encryption between the current block of plain text and the key
            try {
                ctBlock = AES.encrypt(ptBlock, key);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //now put the cipher text block we just got into the final cipher text array
            for( int k = (i-1)*16; k < (i*16)-1; k++){
                ct[k] = ctBlock[k-16];
            }
        }
    }

    return ct;
}
```

it says the error is on this line

```
ct[k] = ctBlock[k-16];
```

which doesnt make much sense. The array ct is of length 48, and ctBlock is len 16 and in the case of where this error is in the for loop, i is equal to 2 or 3 so i am adding a size 16 byte array to either the 2nd third of the array ct or the 3rd third. and like i said i traced it out on paper and it seemed legit so idk!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case when `i = 3`.

```
for( int k = (i-1)*16; k < (i*16)-1; k++){
    ct[k] = ctBlock[k-16];
}
```

Here -

- k starts from 32
- Condition becomes 32 < 47
- Array index for `ctBlock` becomes 32 - 16 = 16, and bam! Array index is out of bound!

Quick fix -

```
for( int k = (i - 1) * 16; k < (i * 16) - 1; k++){
    ct[k] = ctBlock[k - (16 * (i - 1))];
}
```

Comment: ohh gotcha! didnt even think about that. Thank you very much Sayem! It works now :D

Answer (score 0):

If `i == 3`, like you said, then `k == 32` to begin with and increases to `47`. You say that `ctBlock` is a size 16 array, in which case trying to access the elements at indicies `16` through `31` would throw the error.